# Using Split in Python while escaping delimiter in brackets

Tags: python, string, split

I have a string:

*Apple iPhone 6 (Space Grey, 32 GB), Apple iPhone 6 (Space Grey, 32 GB)*

I want to spilt the string with delimiter = ',' but want to escape the ones in bracket.
I have used as below :

```
s= "Apple iPhone 6 (Space Grey, 32 GB), Apple iPhone 6 (Space Grey, 32 GB)"
s.split(",")
```

which gives the output:

```
['Apple iPhone 6 (Space Grey','32 GB)','Apple iPhone 6 (Space Grey','32 GB)']
```

but I want output as below

```
['Apple iPhone 6 (Space Grey, 32 GB)','Apple iPhone 6 (Space Grey, 32 GB)']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to do this is to reject for `)` after `,`:

```
import re
s= "Apple iPhone 6 (Space Grey, 32 GB), Apple iPhone 6 (Space Grey, 32 GB)"
re.split(",(?![^(]*?\))\s*", s)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
s.replace("), ", ")|").split('|')                                                                                                                                                   
# ['Apple iPhone 6 (Space Grey, 32 GB)', 'Apple iPhone 6 (Space Grey, 32 GB)']
```

Comment: Very interesting and simple answer. What does .split('|') do?

Comment: I used the | so as to not confuse the split with the commas, and to give an exact split  between the two items

Comment: Sorry. I didn't fully see the previous replace!! Now I see!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, it is an over kill, but if you want to use built-in functions, you can do it this way:

```
>>> s = 'Apple iPhone 6 (Space Grey, 32 GB), Apple iPhone 6 (Space Grey, 32 GB)'
>>> splitted_s = s.split(',')
>>> [','.join([a, b]).strip() for a, b in list(zip(splitted_s, splitted_s[1:]))[::2]]
    ['Apple iPhone 6 (Space Grey, 32 GB)', 'Apple iPhone 6 (Space Grey, 32 GB)']
```

Comment: That works... WIll stop searching... HAHAHAHA! Very interesting (and complex) answer

Answer (score 0):

Well, one more... easier than my previous one, I hope

```
s = "Apple iPhone 6 (Space Grey, 32 GB), Apple iPhone 6 (Space Grey, 32 GB)"

parts = s.split(")")[:-1]

result = []
for part in parts:
   result.append(part.replace(",", "").strip() + ")")

print(result)
```

Comment: Your code will return `['Apple iPhone 6 (Space Grey, 32 GB', ' Apple iPhone 6 (Space Grey, 32 GB)']`, which is not what he wanted

Comment: @kalma ur ans is not generic, i have a multiple rows which i have to split by "," i just need to escape the , inside brackets.